# What was the first anime to have a "please notice me senpai" moment?

Tags: tropes, anime-history, meme

This meme has been prevalent in English-speaking part of the internet, but so far no one really knows its true origins. I've searched for something similar in the Japanese sphere of the internet and I haven't really found anything either. So far as I know, it seems to be made up and not really existent in anime. Yes, there has been stories about kouhai wanting to be with their senpais, but it doesn't seem like this particular line could have come from an anime.

What anime could have started this meme?

Comment: Related: ["I Hope Senpai Will Notice Me"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-hope-senpai-will-notice-me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be perfectly honest there was no original "notice me senpai" moment in anime. The way it started is when a female character has feelings for a guy, but she never manages to tell him, and this just happens again and again. My guess is that it was probably a fan of one of these anime that made the first meme.

As for what anime was used in the first "notice me senpai" meme, neither I nor anyone else would be able to give you a definitive answer.

Unless you got Google themselves to look it up for you :P

(I'm sorry that this probably wasn't the answer you were looking for, but I've watched a lot of romantic comedy type anime, but have never actually heard someone say that).

Comment: I agree, it's probably something that probably slowly formed a meme from the stereotypical shoujo girls usually calling their love senpai, and wanting attention from them, rather than originating from a particular series

Answer (score 16):

**In real-life Japanese culture**, many people do hope to get and attempt to get the attention of their love interest without ever voicing it or being direct, so **this is not an anime/manga-specific trope** but rather works of anime/manga are incorporating a very standard experience of elementary/jr. high/high schoolers in Japan past and through to the present. In other words, a particular anime did not start the meme, but rather some particular anime was simply the first to document the real-life occurrence of such moments. ***Shoujo* manga magazines such as *Ribon* often feature color page spreads of advice and instructions on what hairstyles, fashion, and accessories could help you be noticed by the guy you like** (I personally find this very dubious, having taught in 5th~6th grade in Japanese public schools... I'd be surprised if any of the boys are paying attention to how darling a girl's pencil case is and thereby thinking, "Oh, she's good at being cute. I like her now," but I digress), so **from a young age, Japanese girls are encouraged in this practice** of trying to attract a love interest without needing to confess her feelings to him directly (so that he will get interested in her before he realized she's interested in him).

*Sempai* (「先輩」) are upperclassmen *in some sense* to whom a Japanese person will always be kouhai (「後輩」, underclassmen) throughout their lives after graduation. There is no analogous system to the *sempai/kouhai* system in Western culture.  ***Sempai* are *often* older, but not always**: more important than age is the person’s year in school or number of years in the shared *bukkatsu* (student club), company, etc. at the time that the *kouhai* enters said school, club, or company. This is true of both males and females, so we cannot say that a meme developed out of only girls in romance-focused series thinking secretly about their *sempai*; in *shounen* action anime, boys pine away for girls who they think might be out of their league too, whether older or the same age. For example, I'm a member of the manga student group at my university in Japan, and we all call each other by “-san.”  Even though they're all younger than me (since I'm a grad student and they're undergrads), it would be totally inappropriate for me to start calling them in *yobisute* (that is, without a respectful name suffix) because they either 1) are my *sempai* in terms of number of years of membership in the club, or 2) they entered the club at the same time as me. If you enter university as a freshman and meet a sophomore who is your own age, he/she is automatically your *sempai* by virtue of being a grade ahead of you.  Then, even if you have not seen your *sempai* in decades and you are now both middle-aged and working at different companies of equal repute, when you meet again he/she is still your superior to whom you must look up to, defer to, and serve; there is no evening-out of level in Japanese *sempai/kouhai* culture.

You write,

> "it seems to be made up and not really existent in anime. . . . it doesn't seem like this particular line could have come from an anime."

If you are asking, which anime first featured this exact line of inner monologue where the *seiyuu* voices it, you might be correct in that the exact wording cannot be found; however, that would be hard to confirm. Since the *sempai/kouhai* relationship and the don't-confess-feelings-directly cultural element are both so standard in Japanese culture, it would be hard to pin-point and verify the earliest case of this moment documented in the anime medium, because **you would need to be looking at the earliest anime TV films and series produced in [the 60s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_anime#1960s) that contain school settings**, or possibly you would even need to check through the older [propaganda films and shorts of the previous decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_anime) (which are difficult to get ahold of, even for anime scholars). That would entail investigating all the genres ranging from *shounen* sci-fi to *shoujo* sports series. Though I am not very familiar with 60s anime, I can say, at the least, that **you can find this "notice me, senpai" *moment*, though not the exact phrasing, in many anime produced in the 70s, 80s, and 90s**. Such an English phrase would be summarizing the moment that we do often see occur in anime.

See also my [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/22209/8134) to this [question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22208/why-are-there-so-many-perverted-virgins-in-anime/):

> . . . a major format of Japanese romance is to like someone who you are not friends with for a long time, and finally "confess" your feelings in a sudden love letter, on St. Valentine's Day, or on graduation day, in which the recipient must abruptly decide whether or not he/she has romantic interest in the other person -- who might not have been on the recipient's radar whatsoever. This can result in either being turned down on the spot ("I don't even know you"), a willingness to try to go on a couple dates ("Maybe I could get interested in you"), or the first-choice being the recipient is overjoyed ("I secretly pined away for you for years too!"). A lot of romantic feelings and sexual desire are never confessed, but some that are get rejected due to the format in which the potential couple does not get to know each other through friendship or casual dating before a major DTR (defining the relationship) event takes place, or reciprocal feelings are confessed right after the graduation ceremony and the respective parties part ways to go to different schools for high school or university, so the mutual interest doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: I have added some details to the "sempai are often older, but not always" paragraph in an answer about that specific question at the Japanese SE [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28826/4547).

Answer (score 2):

'Notice me senpai!' Really didn't originate from anywhere, it's more of a reference to when there's a romance in Animes that deal with school life. Before it somehow always was the girl chasing the guy (and still is). So I'm betting that whatever was the first anime to have an older male protagonist and a younger female protagonist, is most likely where it really originated from. If you watch older romance anime's their almost always about school life, so I'm assuming as time went on people noticed the pattern and came up with that meme.